# Errors on Firebase Authentication for iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are currently experiencing a tricky error to nail down with Firebase authentication. It has locked out all of iOS users from our application, so this is critical for us to figure out or our business will fail.

We’re using the Firebase Authentication package for email and google sign in. We haven’t had any issues until a few months ago when users started reporting the sign in button is unresponsive. For some inexplicable reason, the development team is unable to recreate the issue on our phones, which is why we missed it in QA testing. Our login code perfectly follows the Firebase documentation.

We did find an error from the Firebase packages saying that a URL exceeds length limits for this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword

"2021-03-29 20:58:04.388172-0700 Runner[5880:392924] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF300005] URL length exceeds limits, truncating recorded URL - https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword."

We are using:

- firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
- flutter version: 1.5.4+33

Can anyone help us work this out?

Comment: What is your firebase authorization version? 1??? Are you sure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing the code that's failing, it will be impossible to help. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to tag your question with your coding platform and what firebase products you're using.